# Can I insert a file in my standalone python program to be downloaded by users as a template file

Tags: python, templates, insert, python-standalone

I'm doing python coding self study and not a programmer.. this is my first entry here. Not sure if this is doable, (I have a very little knowledge about programming) but here it is.

Is it possible to insert a file, like a template, for the user to download in a standalone program? Tried searching online but have not been successful, maybe I just don't know how to term it.

Any suggestion is very welcome.. thanks in advance..

[When user clicks 'Download template', they can download an Excel template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHeMj.png)

User can download the template that I inserted in a program, that is if inserting file in a standalone program is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking is if you can embed a file into the `.py` itself (which is what I think you mean when you are saying standalone), to which the answer is no. It might be possible to compile the program into an `exe` using [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/), but not sure how efficient or feasible that is.

If you *really* need this to be only one `.py`, I would suggest hosting it somewhere online for free and having python [download the file from the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-to-download-a-file-over-http).

If I am being honest, the best way to go about doing this is to ditch the "standalone program" requirement and just shipping the template in a zip file with the `.py` file.

### Edit: Creating the file on-demand

This slipped my mind as an idea (probably because it is the most involved and difficult way to do it), but you may be able to use something like [XSLX writer](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html) to **create** the excel file on demand. Would require you to code a function that makes a brand new excel file from scratch, but this would not require downloads, zip files, or an executable, so it would be truly standalone (minus the added `pip` dependency).

Be warned though, I think python and XLSX can be finicky at times.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. will consider it. another lesson to study..

Comment: Always more to learn! If you feel like the question was answered, please accept the answer (if you want to leave it open for more answers, this is also great; just want to make sure the question does not remain dormant if you consider it done)

Comment: I'm still having a hard time navigating the comments section and on how to reply and to make mentions.. thanks so much..

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.. i did what u suggested and created a generate template function but in a very simple code as i only want to create an excel template with only the first two rows populated, header and sample entries.